# How to create a messaging service?

Tags: client, client-server, xmpp, messaging, server-side

I want to create a messaging service that uses the XMPP protocol.  How would I implement the server-side as well as the client side aspects of this service?  I know I would need a server (like Jabberd 2) that runs the messaging framework.  How hard would this be to set up and get running?  Also what would be the best way to hook up a client program into this service?  How would i start pushing messages from one client, through the server, to another client?

Comment: This is a really broad question! Are you trying to program a messaging server/client, or set up an existing one? What do you mean by "hook" a client program into the service - it all boils down to socket programming.

Comment: i am looking to use an xmpp server that someone else has created (but i can run on my own server) and have it serve messages to client software i write in Cocoa

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Server: there are many out there, see http://xmpp.org/software/servers.shtml for a list.

I've used [OpenFire](http://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/openfire/index.jsp) in the past, it's fairly straightforward to set up.

You can add a library like [xmppframework](http://code.google.com/p/xmppframework/) to your Cocoa project to make it a client, and configure it to talk to your XMPP server.

Each client gets an identifier (called a *'jid'*) of the form: **uniquetext@xmppserver.name**, and you send messages from one client to the other by addressing them to the *jid* of the intended recipient.

If you want to play around with simple examples in a scripting language, you can use something like the [examples in the python xmpp library](http://xmpppy.sourceforge.net/) to see how it all works. Use an [xmpp client](http://xmpp.org/software/clients.shtml) like [psi](http://psi-im.org/) to connect as one *jid* and use the examples to connect as another *jid* to send/receive messages through the server.